# Piping commands into awk script

Tags: awk, sed

```
cat sample.log.txt|
    grep INext-DROP-DEFLT|
    sed -e 's/^.*SRC=//' -e 's/ .*DPT=/:/' -e 's/ .*$//' |
    sort|
    uniq|
    ip.awk
```

I'm trying to send this command to an awk script but I don't know how to pipe it. The ip.awk is the script I want to send it to

Comment: `...| awk -f ip.awk` Also, you could look into adding that `sed`functionality into your `awk` script as well.

Comment: @JamesBrown you mean `awk -f ip.awk` ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick help guys! It worked

Comment: Is this a challenge to call all unix commands in a single line? because `awk` can handle all the previous stuff (cat, grep, sed). `sort|uniq` can be replaced by `sort -u` and done after your awk script. You could end up with a simple `awk -f myscript.awk sample.log.txt | sort -u`

Comment: I was required to use both at the same time but yeah it would be more efficient to do it that way

Comment: Whoever is requiring you to use both is an idiot. Stop listening to them.

Comment: If nothing else, at least lose the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)